# Token is null for ADAL getCachedToken() in angular SPA

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

In my angular SPA app I am using adal js to get Azure AD token.I am able to log in but when I use method getCachedToken() ,it is giving me null token value.I am using default sessionstorage and token is available but below line is not returning token value.

```
token = ctx.getCachedToken(clientId);
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The `getCachedToken` method takes the authorization endpoint url as a parameter.

`ctx.getCachedToken('https://graph.microsoft.com')`

Works for me using adal-angular v1.0.17.

Though this shouldn't be necessary as `getCachedToken` is called within the `acquireToken` method.

```js
AuthenticationContext.prototype.acquireToken = function(a, b) {
    var c = this.getCachedToken(a);
    return c ? (this.info("Token is already in cache for resource:" + a)
```

Hope this helps!